# FCM not getting in background after legacy key

Tags: android, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using FCM since version 8.0, As per documentation, data in the `notification` will be received only when the app is in the foreground in the `FCMMessagingService`, but data in the `data` key will be received in both situations, doesn't matter if the app is in foreground or background.

Below is the PHP snippet by which server sends a notification

```
$path_to_firebase_cm = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
        $fields = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'notification' => array('title' => 'Title', 'body' => $message,'vibrate'=>"1",'sound'=>"mySound"),
            'data' => array('message' => $message)
        );
```

Android code/class that should receive notification.

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        // Check if message contains a data payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("message"));
        }

        // Check if message contains a notification payload.
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }
}
```

> compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'

Plugin, classpath, and service in manifiest are already added as per requirement

`apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

`classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'`

```
 <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:name=".fcm.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

**ISSUE**

When the app is in foreground, data payload and notification payload both log are displaying and when the app is in background none of the log is getting displayed.

It is working fine with the old projects, an issue is with when we create new Firebase app, that is giving new **LEGACY SERVER KEY** for sending the notification.

Comment: The legacy key does not impact the delivery of the message. Could you please remote it from the title to help the future readers ?

Comment: it should not affect, but I am facing this issue only after the google updated the server keys.

Comment: what you described is the correct behavior for notification-messages (see documentation). The behavior didn't change since FCM was launched. It's possible that your server code change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use only `data` object on your json. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37711082/how-to-handle-notification-when-app-in-background-in-firebase/38795553#38795553).
So your json must be like this

```
 $fields = array(
            'to' => $token,
            'data' => array('message' => $message, 'title' => 'Title', 'body' => $message,'vibrate'=>"1",'sound'=>"mySound")
        );
```

Comment: I can try, but previously it was working fine with this code also. and both field are tottaly different, i think adding an extra field in array does not create an issue at all

Comment: It worked, but I am not getting why it was working fine previously and adding an extra value in PHP Array will not affect because it might be working as per the value based on key.